# WCF is changing my DateTime returned from a jQuery .axaj call in JSON format

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, datetime

I know this question has been asked many times here, but no answer has provided me with a solution yet. Please help, I'm beating my head against the wall.

Problem:
I have a simple ASP.NET web forms app with one page - Default.aspx. This page has jQuery, JSON2, Rick Strahl's ServiceProxy.js, and my javascript file referenced (timezone.js). In the same project I have a WCF service that I call from timezone.js using ServiceProxy (which is a convenient wrapper around jQuery's .ajax POST). The call should return an object that has a DateTime property. I am testing on two client machines in different time zones and getting different results. 
Here are the screenshots of the app hosted is IIS:

EDIT: Looks like StackOverflow isn't letting me post images. Here is the rendered text...

On the GMT machine I get:
Date rendered by js from WCF call: **Fri Sep 28 13:30:00 UTC+0100 2012**

On the Eastern Standard Time machine I get: Date rendered by js from WCF call: 
**Fri Sep 28 08:30:00 EDT 2012**

As you can see on the right side of both screenshots, the WCF call results in different times.

I want complete control over what dates are sent back and I'm this close to converting it to a string on the server and parsing the string in javascript. I also must use POST to a WCF Enabled Ajax Service.

Here is the code behind for Default.aspx

```
public class DateContainerObject
{
    public DateTime theDate { get; set; }
}

public static class DateMaker
{
    public static DateContainerObject MakeDateObj()
    {
        DateContainerObject obj = new DateContainerObject();
        DateTime origUTCDate = new DateTime(2012, 9, 28, 13, 30, 0);
        DateTime newKindDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(origUTCDate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
        obj.theDate = newKindDate;

        return obj;
    }
}

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Literal1.Text = DateMaker.MakeDateObj().theDate.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is the WCF Service code:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class TimeZoneService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public DateContainerObject GetDateObject()
    {
        return DateMaker.MakeDateObj();
    }
}
```

This is the timezone.js code:

$(function () {

```
var dObj = {};
var proxy = new ServiceProxy("/TimeZoneService.svc/", { isWcf: true });
proxy.invoke("GetDateObject",
        dObj,
        function (result) {
            $('#spanDateJSRender').text(result.theDate);
        },
        function (e) {
            alert(e);
        },
        function () { },
        false
        );
```

});

I've tried specifying the DateTimeKind to all different values, but it doesn't give me accurate date and time. I've also tried using DateTimeOffset and I get the same results.
What can I do with this example to get the exact DateTimes that are created on the server to render in the browser?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I assume you service is making use of REST, right?

Comment: This is a POST to a WCF Service. The service only implements POST so not fully REST spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to wrap this up. I'm converting my DateTime objects to strings and having JavaScript parse them on the client. This doesn't feel too good, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Both 'Fri Sep 28 13:30:00 UTC+0100 2012' and 'Fri Sep 28 08:30:00 EDT 2012' represent the same point in time (Sep 28 12:30 UTC). If you want a uniform representation of the date, don't use the `toString` method to convert the `result.theDate`, use something like `toUTCString()` instead.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. However, I am only using ToString in the server rendering code where this issue is not present at all. The problem I am having is getting the WCF service to return me the date and time I specified it. In this example I want Sept 28, 2012 13:30 to be sent down to the browser in any time zone.

Comment: The problem is that JS doesn't have the concept of an "unspecified" date time - IIRC it's always stored as UTC and you can print it out to UTC or to local time. One option you have is to send the data as UTC (`new DateTime(2012, 9, 28, 13, 30, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)`, and at the client use the `toUTCString` when printing out the date. Or, as you suggested, use strings instead of dates if you want to control the formatting at the server side.

Comment: Carlos. Thanks again for your help. I ended up converting my datetime ToString("f") on the server and having the JavaScript do the parsing. It's doesn't give me that warm fuzzy feeling doing that, but it works.